# Login fails for sql users after data base migration on a new server

Tags: sql-server, ssms, database-migration

We recently moved all our databases on a new server (what a pain) and we felt on a common issue. But that issue dosen't seems to have a specific solution.

All the users, (and all the applications using these users) fail to connect, or fail to query the database.

**WE CAN SEE THESE USERS** in SQL management studio, they're here, in the security file at the bottom, just like everything is normal.

If i delete one of those users, then recreate it, with all the same parameters, it suddently work.

I'm aware of security, login, users rights, i have an idea of what owned schema is, but not more.

But it seems like there is something  more, or there is something i don't see correctly. Something that binds the user to a specific sql server, and this something isin't updated when you move a database onto a new server.

What is this thing ? Any idea ? Any idea how to apply the right value on it ?

Comment: Probably your user mappings was not migrated. Open properties of any sql login which is unable to login and check "user mapping" section, it should has mapping to your particular DB.

Comment: When i open properties, i see the folowings : General, Owned Shema, Membership, securables, extended Properties...

Comment: Hmm... that means you're opening properties of user in particular DB, not sql login. SQL logins are located in "security" folder outside of all Dbs. Check if there exists sql login corresponded to DB user.

Comment: Ho i see... well, mapping all the users back to their databases... will be kind of long, what if i don't remember everything... Guess there is not a lot of choices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments, server level Security\Logins need to map to database level Security\Users.  I've seen scripts in the past provided by MSDN pages that help you script out logins when migrating from one SQL Server instance to another.  Right now it sounds like you have "orphaned users", and might check out this page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175475(v=sql.110).aspx

That might offer some help to clean them up.  I'm not familiar with the exact commands, but you should also be able to script the security mapping of users to databases, too, even more so if you still have access to the old server.

Comment: i suppose i could loop over all the users, check the old db, and apply some sort of mapping on the moved users with these kind of commands. I don't know if i will... Sounds better than doing it one by one though

Answer (score 1):

Note, when you create a new instance of SQL Server, it will *default* to Windows Authentication *only*. Then if you use the Database Migration Assistant tool, all the users *will* be created properly -- but you'll still be unable to log in with SQL Server Authentication until you turn that on: [https://www.stellarinfo.com/blog/how-to-fix-sql-server-database-error-18456/#:~:text=enable%20sql%20authentication](https://www.stellarinfo.com/blog/how-to-fix-sql-server-database-error-18456/#:%7E:text=enable%20sql%20authentication)